# Batch script - how to get digit from number

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 variables "number" and "some":

```bat
SET number=12
SET some=25
```

How can I invoke digits from those variables to use it in regexp?
Something like:

```bat
%number(0)% [0 - %number(1)%] | %some(0)% [0 - %some(1)%]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "invoke digits" but if you just want to get the digits then it depends on how the numbers are.

If they're fixed-width (like always have 2 digits) you can use [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to get the digits

```bat
echo %number:~0,1% %number:~1,1%
```

If the numbers have variable width then you need to do some math with [`set /a`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

```bat
set /a tens=(number/10) %% 10
set /a ones=number %% 10
```

Same thing if you want to do math like `0 - %number(1)%` above